# asp.net identity with domain controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

I need to achieve to authenticate users with their domain user/password, if they're are in the domain controller, but the application should be available for other users as well, who should be authenticated with their own username/password; this should be stored in the application database, and their username/password to be checked against the DB.

So far i started with new asp.net template in vs2015, choosing Individual User Accounts.
I'm able to authenticate users agains domain controller, but if that is succeeded I'm unable to store the user to HttpContext.User property.

In SignInManager i call PasswordSignIn and return Success or Failure depending on AD check.

```
public SignInStatus PasswordSignIn(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout) {
  if(AuthenticateAD(userName, password)) {
//
// to create identity/principal and assign to HttpContext.User
//
    return SignInStatus.Success;
  }
  else {
    return SignInStatus.Failure;
  }
}

public bool AuthenticateAD(string username, string password) {
  using(var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainname")) {
    return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
  }
}
```

thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

The only way this really works is if you create proxy users in your application for users in AD. Essentially, you just set up a script that populates new users/updates existing users based on the data in AD on a schedule (nightly, etc. based on your needs). Then, you're dealing with just one type of user whether they're part of the domain or external. The only change you need to make is to selectively authenticate via AD or via the standard password authentication. Either way, the same user principal is in play.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADFS and allow users to choose where to authenticate. It is quite trivial to implement using default template. Just like usual login mechanics with Sign-in via google and local account.

I think this is most correct way of doing things, because domain users may end up with Kerberos/Ntlm, if they want, and it lowers complexity of your system.

Here is a WS-Fed example: [Using Claims in your Web App is Easier with the new OWIN Security Components](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/21/using-claims-in-your-web-app-is-easier-with-the-new-owin-security-components.aspx)

For other stuff you can create app with default template. This app will have external authentication stuff as example.